# preposition 'to' after verb 'talk'

Tags: grammar, verbs, prepositions, prepositional-phrases

I'm confused whether it is correct to use 'to' after 'talk' or not?
Some examples would really be appreciated.

Comment: Please clarify what exactly you find confusing. I can talk. I can also talk to you. I can even talk with you or at you. And more examples can be found in a good dictionary, including bilingual dictionaries translating the difference into your mother tongue.

Comment: If you intend to refer to the person to whom the talking was directed (called _listener, recipient, goal, dative_ or _indirect object_) with the verb _talk_, then the answer is that it's obligatory to use _to_. One of the peculiarities of _talk_ is that it does not allow the dative alternation: _I talk to you_ but not _*I talk you._ This is the opposite of the rule for _tell,_ which **requires** the dative alternation: _I tell you_ but not _*I tell to you._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using 'to' after 'talk' is *sometimes* correct.

It is correct when there is a target/audience for the talking, e.g.

> He talked to himself a lot.
>
> Are you talking to me?

It is not correct when you are just describing the action of talking, but *not* describing the audience.

> We went into the office so we could talk.
>
> I talk quietly because my neighbor complains.